# postgresql json - seach if arrays includes an element

Tags: json, postgresql

Im newbie,

i have 2 json's:

1. alergy_to

   {"0":"carrot","1":"banana","2": "pepper"}
2. food_constains

   {"0":"banana", "1": "milk"}

how to check if my "food_constains" json field constains any alergens which is listed in alergy_to  json

and return true or false, or similar value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED ANSWER**

```
WITH alergy_to(data) AS ( VALUES
  ('{"0":"carrot","1":"banana","2": "pepper"}'::JSON)
), food_contains(data) AS ( VALUES
  ('{"0":"banana", "1": "milk"}'::JSON)
)
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN EXISTS(
    SELECT true
    FROM alergy_to at,json_each_text(at.data) alergy_item,
     food_contains fc, json_each_text(fc.data) food_item
    WHERE food_item.value = alergy_item.value
  )
  THEN TRUE
  ELSE FALSE
END;
```

For more details you can refer to [**JSON Postgres documentation**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html)

Comment: Tkank you very much! i've edited it to:  WITH alergy_to(data) AS ( VALUES
  ('{"0":"carrot","1":"banana","2": "pepper"}'::JSON)
), food_contains(data) AS ( VALUES
  ('{"0":"banana", "1": "milk"}'::JSON)
)
SELECT TRUE as IHAVEALERGENS
FROM alergy_to at,json_each_text(at.data) alergy_item,
     food_contains fc, json_each_text(fc.data) food_item
WHERE food_item.value = alergy_item.value group by IHAVEALERGENS;

Comment: and one more variation - with tables: `WITH alergy_to(data) AS ( VALUES ('["carrot","banana","pepper"]'::JSON)), food_contains(data) AS ( VALUES ('["banana", "milk"]'::JSON))
SELECT TRUE as IHAVEALERGENS
FROM alergy_to at,json_array_elements_text(at.data) alergy_item,
     food_contains fc, json_array_elements_text(fc.data) food_item
WHERE food_item.value = alergy_item.value group by IHAVEALERGENS;`

Comment: `SELECT true` is not a good idea, because the query returns as many rows as matched values. In particular, it returns no rows if there are no matched values. If you use an aggregate function, e.g. `SELECT count(*) > 0`, you always get one row with a boolean value.

Comment: `EXISTS`is probably the best approach but `SELECT EXISTS(..);` would be just perfect.